# Checking selected value in ComboBox - SilverLight4

Tags: c#, silverlight, combobox

**SOLVED**

I'm trying to make some actions when specific position is selected from combobox, but can't get it to work, Google gave me answer that doesn't work, though people say it does.

So I've got this in XAML:

```
    <ComboBox Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="178,96,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" SelectionChanged="comboBox1_SelectionChanged" SelectedValuePath="Content">

        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">Szafa</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Segment</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Łóżko</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Stół</ComboBoxItem>

    </ComboBox>
```

And this in XAML.cs

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((comboBox1.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString() == "Szafa") 
            MessageBox.Show("TEST"); 
    }
```

Also tried this:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string UserSelect = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        if (UserSelect == "Szafa") 
            MessageBox.Show("TEST"); 
    }
```

SilverLight plugin stops on 100% and doesn't show any content. After I remove if condition, it works... What's wrong?

SOLVED

I solved this via:

```
        if ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedValue.ToString() == "Szafa")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("TEST");
        }
```

For any future people who come here...

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer instead of editing your question to say 'SOLVED'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't answer this for first 8h, so doing it now. I solved this via:

```
        if ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedValue.ToString() == "Szafa")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("TEST");
        }
```

For any future people who come here...